# why using eval and parsonJson together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think jquery $.parseJSON can convert jsons string to JavaScript object, why someone still use eval($.parseJSON) together?

Comment: Do you mean `eval($.parseJSON(x))`? That's just stupid - eval expects a string, not a JavaScript object. It's only meaningful if x contains the json `"alert('foo')"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like redundant at all.

jQuery `parseJSON` function uses native JSON in browsers that support it. According to Douglas Crockford (the author of original JSON specification), *"the parse method uses the eval method to do the parsing, guarding it with several regular expressions to defend against accidental code execution hazards."* 
If the browser does not support JSON natively, jQuery uses `new Function` constructor to return parsed object, which is eval() equivalent with some scoping differences.

Comment: Also, seems like eval($.parseJSON()) could not be valid since eval() expects to string parameter, and $.parseJSON() returns object.

Comment: Actually, calling `eval` on objects/arrays simply returns the object/array - so it is valid.

Comment: @Idan: 10x, good to know.